# SQL Server remote connection using SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: sql-server

I want to connect my SQL Server Management Studio to a remote database.

My question is: what is the right format for server name?

```
122.XXX.XXX.XXX\instance,port
```

Any idea?

Comment: Yes the format seems correct.

Comment: For example to connect my docker sql server I have such string `localhost,1433\sql1`. So check this variant also

Answer (score 0):

This 122.XXX.XXX.XXX\instance,port format the you have entered is correct, First you enter the server name or IP address, then server instance entered aftre "\"  then port entered and separated by ","

Comment: The instance name is not needed (ignored) when a port is specified.

Comment: How we specify the instance name in this situation?

Comment: The instance name is not needed because the client connects directly to the specified host and port. The purpose of the instance name is to dynamically determine the port the specified instance is listening on by querying the SQL Browser service.